# Need help on query to select data from union of two tables in Orcacle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Need help in below query:
My requirement is, if role_id is existing for a user in si_org_roles ( first union), then no need to pick up data from audit tables 
( its used for  list of user deleted from a role) and note that a user can have multiple org - role, ie. org-role to role is many - one relationship.

```
SELECT  m.user_id, m.org_role_id, m.last_update_date,ro.role_id 
FROM si_user_org_roles m,si_org_roles ro where m.org_role_id = ro.org_role_id 
and ro.role_id = 100074
union 
SELECT  au.user_id_o,
  au.org_role_id_o,
  au.last_update_date_o,
  ru.role_id
FROM si_user_org_roles_au au,si_org_roles ru
WHERE au.transaction_type = 'Delete'
and au.org_role_id_o = ru.org_role_id
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Here is what I gather from it: You have users plus their org_roles in si_user_org_roles and in si_user_org_roles_au. Some users in only one of the tables, some in both. You want users with role_id 100074. As mentioned tables only hold org_role, one must join with si_org_roles, to only get records for role_id 100074. Now, if a user is present in si_user_org_roles you want to show all their records for role_id 100074 in si_user_org_roles. If a user is not present in si_user_org_roles, you want all their records for role_id 100074 in si_user_org_roles_au. Is that so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT  m.user_id,
        m.org_role_id,
        m.last_update_date,
       ro.role_id 
  FROM si_user_org_roles m,
       si_org_roles ro
 where m.org_role_id = ro.org_role_id 
  and ro.role_id = 100074
union 
SELECT  au.user_id_o,
  au.org_role_id_o,
  au.last_update_date_o,
  ru.role_id
FROM si_user_org_roles_au au,si_org_roles ru
WHERE au.transaction_type = 'Delete'
and au.org_role_id_o = ru.org_role_id
and not exists(select 'X' 
                 from si_user_org_roles m,
                      si_org_roles ro
                where m.org_role_id = ro.org_role_id
                  and ro.org_role_id = ru.org_role_id 
                  and ro.role_id = 100074)
```

Totally untested, since you didn't provide table definitions or sample data.

The idea here is that the first half (before union) does the select based on role_id, if there is no data available, the first query will return no rows.  Then the second half (after union) goes after the audit data, but, I added the exists clause.  The exists clause essentially checks if the first half returned data, and if it did, prevents the second half from returning data.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` clause to skip the selection from the audit table.

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT role_id
            FROM   si_org_roles
            WHERE  role_id = 100074); -- to check the role_id is avlailable in si_org_roles table.
```

Try like this,

```
SELECT m.user_id, m.org_role_id, m.last_update_date,ro.role_id 
FROM   si_user_org_roles m,
       si_org_roles ro 
WHERE  m.org_role_id = ro.org_role_id 
AND    ro.role_id = 100074
UNION 
SELECT au.user_id_o, au.org_role_id_o, au.last_update_date_o, ru.role_id
FROM   si_user_org_roles_au au,
       si_org_roles ru
WHERE  au.transaction_type = 'Delete'
AND    au.org_role_id_o = ru.org_role_id
AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT role_id
                   FROM   si_org_roles
                   WHERE  role_id = 100074);
```